# Unable to add a source with url

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios5, cocoapods

[!] Unable to add a source with url `git@github.com:CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master-1`. You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.   please any help

Comment: CocoaPods expects to own the repo named master  or check xcodeproject folder should be same as of cocoapods

Comment: SKT, rajesh> anyone knows solution to this?

Comment: Which answer worked for you? I tried all but only Tahir's answer worked for `pod update`.

Answer (score 37):

Please follow this [link](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3631) for this problem. Its possible to forgott set your newly install Xcode path on command-line tool. **Xcode-->Preferences-->Locations-->Command line tool --> set your Xcode.**

Comment: Seems odd to claim here that the correct answer is the first thing on that link, when the user there clearly said that it didn't fix their problem...

Answer (score 30):

You may need to reset your command line tools:

```
sudo xcode-select -r
```

I was receiving the same error message. Then I noticed, that the wrong Xcode environment was selected (it pointed to an old version which I deleted in the meantime). The command above resets it to the default command line path.

Alternatively you might have no command line tools installed. In that case, download them from the Apple site and install them.

Comment: Worked! How did you know this is an answer?

Answer (score 11):

Go to ~/.cocoapods/repos and run git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master

Comment: I tried every answer here but this is the ONLY one that produced results after `pod update`

Comment: `cd ~/.cocoapods/repos && git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master` worked for me

Comment: I got this error: error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 20032 MiB | 926 KiB/s    
`fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed`

Answer (score 6):

When you get above error it means, you didn't do the **pod setup**

instructions:

1. First install the cocoapods in you Mac if it is not already installed. Use terminal.

   ## Xcode 7 + 8

   sudo gem install cocoapods --pre

   ## Xcode 7

   sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6
   sudo gem install cocoapods
2. Set up the pod using command **pod setup**

after doing these initial set up you are ready to make your project as work space project.
You can follow these commands using terminal

1. Goto Project location folder : **~/Destop/SampleProject**
2. Create pod file : **pod init**
3. List down your cocoa pods init it :

   ```
   # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
   #platform :ios, '9.0'

   target 'SampleProject' do
   # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
   use_frameworks!

   # Pods for SampleProject
   pod 'SlideMenuControllerSwift'


   target 'SampleProjectTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
   # Pods for testing
   end

   target 'SampleProjectUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
   end
   ```

   end

it will help you.

**or else**

After installation of cocoapods than you can download the cocoa master repo manually into Mac.

```
    $ cd /Users/username/.cocoapods/repos 
    $ git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
```

Answer (score 6):

1. `$ cd /Users/username/.cocoapods/repos`
2. remove folder `master` if it exists
   `rm -rf master`
   `$ git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master`
3. `pod setup`

that's all.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem , actually the problem was that command line was not able to find a path to my Xcode. Therefore the simplest solution that i found was to give a suitable location of xcode.

For it:

1. Go to Xcode > Preferences
2. Choose Location tab
3. Select the Xcode in Command Line tools:- 
   [image]

thats it. I hope that works for you. All the best

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to `pod setup` first.

Answer (score 1):

Please Follow this steps:

Open Terminal

1] sudo xcode-select -r

2] Xcode-->Preferences-->Locations-->Command line tool --> set your Current Xcode Version.

3] Edit Podfile and save

4] pod install

Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error with only difference that there was different `URL`. I was trying to install `private pods` from private repository. What helped is to add `ssh-key` to profile.

1. Generate `ssh-key` using this guide: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/. Hope this helps.
2. Add it in your profile settings on Bitbucket(or Github or whatever you are using)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have access to the pod spec repo first. For me I wasn't having access.So this issue happened.

Answer (score 0):

This is often happening on initial pod install. I tried all and this steps helped me

Please follow these steps:

1] pod repo update

2] pod install

I hope that works for you. All the best

Answer (score 0):

Meet the same error and I have solved it by :

```
1. Open your terminal
2. Go to the directory    : cd /User/YOUR_NAME/.cocoapods/repos/
3. remove the master file : rm -rf master
4. Clone the CocoaPods    : git clone https://git.coding.net/CocoaPods/Specs.git ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
```

Note. I add the target path `~/.cocoapods/repos/master` to avoid the mistake that your current file path is not `~/.cocoapods/repos/master`

```
5. Run the setup          : pod setup
```