# pod files are showing empty during checkout in new version of xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, podfile

I have developed an application in Xcode version 7 and now I want to run the same application in Xcode version 8.2.1.Do I need to re-install the pod files which I have included in the previous version of Xcode or is there any procedure i need to follow before running it in the new version of Xcode?

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'test' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for test

  target 'testTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'testUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
 pod 'AZSClient'
  pod 'CardIO'
  pod 'Google/Analytics'
  pod 'OpenTok'
  pod 'THCalendarDatePicker', '~> 1.2.6'

end
```

Comment: Show your pod file & error

Comment: `pod update` works for you. No need to reinstall again if you have already installed on prev. version of xcode.

Comment: tried still it shows same error '[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master-1`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.'

Comment: Try this.`$ rm -rf ~/.cocoapods
$ mkdir -p ~/.cocoapods/repos
$ cd ~/.cocoapods/repos
$ git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master` , taken from github issue https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6269

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run 'pod install'? You should have nothing to lose to re-install the pod files.

Comment: Tried with 'pod install' but it is showing the error: '[!] Unable to add a source with url https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git named master-1. You can try adding it manually in ~/.cocoapods/repos or via pod repo add'

Answer (score 0):

You can visit to https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html ,

I have installed your dependancies in one demo project its work fine & build successfully,

Just run `pod install` if you are installing for first time & `pod update` if you are adding new framework or running in newer version.

[image]

I think you have to do this,

Go to ~/.cocoapods/repos & 
run git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master

Or if not works both visit,

[Unable to add a source with url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29301785/unable-to-add-a-source-with-url)

Comment: For both 'pod install' and 'pod update' am getting the same error.
'[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master-1`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.'

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to install the pod again. You have to do only ....

remove the -lPods-(someCocoaPod) lines in the 'Other Linker Flags' list BUT only if $(inherited) is at the top. At first I was unsure, but the reassuring sign was that I still saw references to my cocoapods when I left the edit mode(inherited). I tested in debug and release, both of which were giving me errors, and the problem was immediately resolved

Answer (score 0):

If you have newly installed Xcode 8.2.1 then you may need to update you CocoaPods on mac using https://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/11/updating-cocoapods/

Comment: In my case i have same issue with pods.
So i have completely removed cocoaPods from my mac.
Then installed latest version of pods on my mac.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it manually in ~/.cocoapods/repos or via pod repo add..

Comment: how to do that? can you explain in brief

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022638/pod-install-is-staying-on-setting-up-cocoapods-master-repo

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, Finally resolved it by updated rvm,ruby with openssl and also upgraded git:

Pod install:

**referred:**

[How to update Ruby Version 2.0.0 to the latest version in Mac OSX Yosemite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194032/how-to-update-ruby-version-2-0-0-to-the-latest-version-in-mac-osx-yosemite)

rvm get stable

brew update

brew doctor

brew install openssl

rvm install ruby-2.3.3 (or whatever version)

rvm use (ruby version here)  i.e. rvm use ruby-2.3.3

//rvm gemset create NAME   i.e. rvm gemset create rails41
//gem install rails -v 4.1

rvm list(ruby)
rvm –default use 2.3.3(Make it as default)

rvm reinstall 2.3.3 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl

sudo gem install cocoapods

pod init

change pod-file and save it(add dependencies)à edit only in sublime text

pod install